# How to remove the white spaces while reading the text from Textfile (i.e In the forms of column)

Tags: java, file-handling

I read the textfile in which data is stored in the form of columns,I want to store the data in an arrayList by splitting all the lines.
How to remove whitespaces that occured while storing data into textfile.

```
 try {
       fr = new FileReader(f);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
       String skip=br.readLine();
       String line;
        String ss[]=null;
       while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
       {
        // ss=line.split(" ");
        // String nt=  line.replaceAll("\\s","");
           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line , " ");
        //   ss=line.split(" ");
         while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
         //  System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(ss[0].replaceAll("\\s", "")));
      String   s1=st.nextToken();

     // ss[0]=s1;
             System.out.println(s1);
             break;
         }
       }

       EmployeeTaxReport emp=new EmployeeTaxReport(Integer.parseInt(ss[0].replaceAll("\\s", "")), Integer.parseInt(ss[1].replaceAll("\\s", "")),Integer.parseInt(ss[2].replaceAll("\\s", "")));
       empreport.add(emp);
       for (EmployeeTaxReport e: empreport) {
         System.out.println(e.empid);

       }

   }catch(Exception ext)
   {
   //   System.out.println("OOPs..The file does not exit.Please input valid file name");
   ext.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: `line.split("\\s+");` will split on one (or more) white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your source code shows the comment

```
//   ss=line.split(" ");
```

I believe you tried this, and found out that it does not do what you wanted.

Change it to :

```
ss = line.split("\\s+");
```

just as suggested by @ElliottFrisch in the comments...